# Device tilt angles getting. Hybrid app. Cordova

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, dom-events, hybrid-mobile-app

I have a function:

```
window.addEventListener("deviceorientation",handleOri,false);
function handleOri(event){
    axisX = event.alpha;
    axisY=event.beta;
    axisZ=event.gamma;
}
```

But I'm getting tilt angles at every tick when device is moving and angles gets according to magnetic northpole. What I really need is to do next thing; user presses button1, and `var a = zeropint.after` pressing button1 variables for tilt and rotation angles must be getting according to this zeropoint. How can I do that? Any solutions to get this angles according not to magnetic pole but according to zeropoint? Is a kind of calibration device and must be thus. Can anyone help me to deal with it?

Comment: please draft your question in proper format, other people who may want to answer it or people who may want to refer it can not, due to improper formatting.

Comment: Which format is propper?

Comment: Olejjon by format i mean please separate the code, separate your question on new line, not just like a single para. hope this makes sense.

Comment: Olejjon thats okay, however questions actually improves our community, right!!

Comment: Guys,enyone alive here?

Comment: *anyone //for enyone

Comment: Still no one know how to solve this?

Comment: Olejjon, its strange... but seems to be tough question that anybody never came across or something. wait for sometime.